# Were unsuspecting visitors pranked at the East Taihang Glasswalk?

Tags: china, tricks

The [East Taihang Glasswalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Taihang_Glasswalk) is a skywalk in the mountains in China.

It purportedly had special effect that makes it appear to crack when you step into it.

- [Atlas Obscura](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/china-cracking-glass-bridge-prank-funny-cruel)

> One glass bridge in China is getting a lot of attention right now after ratcheting up the terror by adding the illusion that the glass floor is cracking underneath people’s feet. Depending on your perspective, it’s either a hilarious prank or a cruel joke.

- [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/culture/internet/shattered-glass-bridge-china-tourists-video/):

> the gimmick was so believable the East Taihang administration issued
> an apology assuring the public the cracks were just an "effect" to
> make the bridge experience more "provocative."

- [YouTube: Tourist terrified by new glass walkway that cracks under weight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo0NJsr5m4I)
- [YouTube: China Glass Bridge - Crack Effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtUOOR5rQYk)

I have not found a reliable source for this.

While I don't doubt the existence of the cracking glass bridge, I find hard to believe that the administration would play such prank on visitors, at least not without some clear warning beforehand.

Without further evidence, I'd bet that these terrified reaction videos are acted.

Can someone confirm?

Comment: Would you consider [*The Telegraph*](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/destinations/asia/china/articles/east-taiheng-glass-walkway-cracks/) to be a reliable source? That, and others, are referenced in your own Wikipedia link. But whether or not the videos use actors isn't relevant.

Comment: _Would you consider The Telegraph to be a reliable source?_
In this context, not really.

Comment: What would you consider to be a reliable source? Whether you believe it to be true, has no bearing on the reliability of a source, and *The Telegraph* is about as reliable as the media goes. Nor would the use of actors imply any kind of proof that the glass bridges cannot be real.

Comment: @WeatherVane I added some clarification.

Comment: So what is the specific claim? That the videos are faked? Or that there is no warning? Why would visitors not be alarmed when the FX are played, even with a warning? Skeptics Stack Exchange is for challenging notable claims, such as pseudoscience and biased results. How does your disbelief fit that?

Comment: @WeatherVane: That people were pranked seems like a notable claim to me. I've edited to hopefully make that clearer.

Comment: I see the difficulty in answering this is in finding a source that would be convincing (either way). News media have a long history of repeating light and inconsequential foreign news stories without vetting, but what other source would mention it?

Comment: @Oddthinking I see. Some of the Wikipedia references (*CNET*, *Inverse* and *Mashable*) mention an official apology, but their links to it are broken.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Oooh, I like your thinking. A (working) link to an official apology would be a great basis for an answer.

Comment: The Internet Archive [has that link archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20171009132458/http://www.baizhi360.com/article/8546), but I can't read Chinese. It's a defunct Chinese site which appears to quote the official apology. Not a news agency site; Google Translate on the [About us](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606181639/http://www.baizhi360.com/article/1) page makes it sound more like a forum or discussion site. Google Translate on the linked article itself makes it sound (to this westerner) as if the quoted apology was actually tongue-in-cheek and making light of the situation.

Comment: The CGTN link which is included in the Q is probably as official as you'll get from China on something like this. @DanGetz: google translate works on that, but there's not much extra evidence there. They have the same footage from CGTN, which pretty typical of "me too" Chinese news sites.

Comment: Euronews had somewhat diff footage, but it's very brief https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK2jFqkh-nE No discussion how much warnings were given.